# iOS 7 UITableView Not Getting Right Cell Height Until Refresh

Tags: ios, uitableview

For some odd reason, my table view sets the height of each custom UITableViewCell to a default value of 44.0f despite me explicitly returning a value of 113.0f in the datasource method. I made sure that I set my view controller as the datasource and delegate so that's not the issue but I'm completely stumped. I saw another SO post where someone was asking a similar question, the tableview wasn't getting the proper cell height until after a forced refresh. I'm even calling `[tableView reloadData]` in every possible uiviewcontroller method and that's not changing anything. Anyone have any ideas/possible fixes?

EDIT:

So here's the weird part. The cell's are visually getting set to the right height but their frame's are returning a value of 44.0f. What's more, all the subviews are sized down to 44.0f even though when I tap a cell, all 113 pixels gets highlighted.

Comment: are you using custom cell of height 44 while loading cell to your table view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I have a UITableViewCell subclass and in my table view delegate method, rowHeightForIndexPath or whatever it's called, I'm returning a value of the tableView height/5 which comes out to 113. It's just on the app launch but once I navigate away and come back, the heights are fine.

Comment: Might be wrong here but I think UITableView used to have a setting for the heights of its cells, and then the cells themselves have their own real frame height.

Answer (score 0):

If you use prototype cells, or if you load their interface from a .xib file, check if they have the right height in the Interface Builder

Comment: Nah I'm not using IB, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: So what is the right height if you use prototype cells in IB? In my case, the height depends on the content. I'm having the same issues as @shadow

Comment: I've found often that with UITableView and UICollectionView, you have to be super careful to define the size of the cells and all their subviews in terms of the superviews bounds, not the frame. I'm not sure why but using the frame property of the UICollectionViewCell makes all the content go wonky.